# jQuery object `toString()` method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I extended the jQuery object to return it's inner HTML...

```
$.fn.toString = function() {
  return this.html();
};

console.log("The inner HTML is: " + $("<div>Here, <i>there</i>, everywhere</div>"));
```

Is there any reason why this is not the default behaviour? Does this break something?

---

### Updated to respond to answers/comments

Firstly, I don't see how it would break much, except for type checks which rely on coercing jQuery objects into string, and matching text in that string. Am I wrong about this?

This returns the `outerHTML` of all elements in a set, concatenated. Does this make any sense to anyone else? To me it makes quite a bit of sense.

```
var li, list;

$.fn.toString = function() {
  var out;
  out = [];
  $.each(this, function(k, v) {
    return out.push($(v)[0].outerHTML);
  });
  return out.join("\n");
};

list = $("<ul>\n  <li>some <a href='/'>link</a> items</li>\n  <li>some <a href='/'>link</a> items</li>\n  <li>some <a href='/'>link</a> items</li>\n  <li>some <a href='/'>link</a> items</li>\n  <li>some <a href='/'>link</a> items</li>\n</ul>");

li = $("li", list);

console.log("The html of it..: " + li);
```

Comment: why don't you use `.text()` ?

Comment: it would override this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: I think it would result in some really bizarre bugs, because there are a lot of situations in JavaScript that involve an implicit call to `.toString()`. (I realize that it'd be convenient sometimes too.)

Comment: You might get an authoritative answer on the jQuery Forums (http://forum.jquery.com/). But speaking personally, I'd find it annoying if that were the default behavior.

Comment: what would be the point - how would you set it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[`Object.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) *returns a string representing the object* (from the doc).**

When talking about a jQuery object, the expected returned value for `Object.toString` is `"[object Object]"`.

Making it return HTML would simply be bad design, and could break stuff up.

Plus, it makes sense to have different explicit methods depending on what we want to retrieve from a jQuery object: [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for HTML, [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for stripping tags.

Comment: So you think that "[object Object]" is an adequate textual representation for any object? Seriously?

Comment: That's what the quotes are for, I knew someone would nitpick on that. The point is, it would never return HTML, that's why it's a bad idea to change that. Anyway, I removed it since it didn't add any substantial value to the answer.

Comment: Yes, HTML would be a bad representation and it's a good idea to have explicit methods for different purposes. But no offense, the statement was a bit misleading. And I can't see why "return something else would simply be bad design" - That's exactly what `toString()` is for.

Comment: None taken, I agree some of my words were ambiguous. Thanks for pointing them out.

Answer (score 5):

Well, jQuery object is home for lot more than just `.html`.If jQuery had to implement the `toString`, it should be generic enough to return based on the selector in jQuery object.

For example, If the selector picked multiple elements The version you have would simply return the first elements html content.

So what I am trying to say is that the `toString` is not simple as you think and I couldn't think of any great usage for `toString` as well.